# Tab Anchor Links Not Working Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tabs

I am pretty familiar with anchor links and how they work. However, I have a site that uses tabs on one page. There are five tabs and when I try and link directly to the second, third, fourth or fifth tab, it just goes to the first tab in every browser except Safari.

Here is the code from the tab list:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#football">Football</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mbball">Men&#39;s Basketball</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#wbball">Women&#39;s Basketball</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#baseball">Baseball</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#vs">Varsity Sports</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is then the anchor portion:

```
<div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="football">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I found a different website that uses tabs and they are able to directly link in every browser, but the code looks the exact same.

```
<ul class="rtabs">
 <li><a href="#football">Football</a></li>
 <li><a href="#mbb">Men's Basketball</a></li>
 <li><a href="#wbb">Women's Basketball</a></li>
 <li><a href="#base">Baseball</a></li>
 <li><a href="#soc-vb">Soccer & Volleyball</a></li>
 <li><a href="#shows">Coaches Radio Shows</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="football">
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You mean the panels aren't switching to the right on content for the current active tab on the page?

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of it you are using twitter bootstrap.

The important components of tabs in bootstrap is that each of the links the href="#id" is the id for the tab-panel you are activating upon click. Each of the anchor tags must have the attribute data-toggle="tab" so that bootstraps javascript knows how to handle the click.

2nd piece and its hard to tell as you've only included partial code is the div's with class "tab-pane" must have a parent wrapper with the class of "tab-content"

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#football">Football</a>

    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#mbball">Men&#39;s Basketball</a>

    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#wbball">Women&#39;s Basketball</a>

    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#baseball">Baseball</a>

    </li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#vs">Varsity Sports</a>

    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="football">
         <h3>Football</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="mbball">
         <h3>Men's Basketball</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="wbball">
         <h3>Women's Basketball</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="baseball">
         <h3>Baseball</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade in" id="vs">
         <h3>Vasity</h3>

    </div>
</div>
<hr/>
```

Working example here...

http://jsfiddle.net/SeanWessell/w71urt1v/